# How to make the bootstrap table rows selectable and remain the selected rows on filter?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to have a bootstrap table and already added input checkboxes to select them as well as a filter to get all selected items (which is totally fine).

After selecting a row, the dataset property "selected" should be set to 1 or true.

But i want to remain all the selected values also when i filter (which should already be fixed by persisting the "selected" attribute in my dataset shouldn't it?)

Currently i can check the checkbox and the checkbox value itself is changed too, but the row.value variable remains the same even if i use v-model for row.value (2-way-databinding)

So. **How can i change the value of an attribute in a bootstrap table?**

```
<b-table show-empty
             stacked="md"
             :items="items"
             :fields="fields"
             :current-page="currentPage"
             :per-page="perPage"
             :filter="filter"
             :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
             :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
             @filtered="onFiltered"
    >

      <template slot="selected" slot-scope="row">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="row.value">
        {{row.value}}
      </template>


      <template slot="name" slot-scope="row">{{row.value}}</template>
      <template slot="sapNumber" slot-scope="row">{{row.value}}</template>
      <template slot="createDate" slot-scope="row">{{ moment(row.value).format('dd DD.MM.YY, hh:mm:ss')}}</template>
      <template slot="master" slot-scope="row">
        <!-- We use @click.stop here to prevent a 'row-clicked' event from also happening -->
        <b-button size="sm" @click.stop="info(row.item, row.index, $event.target)" class="mr-1">
          Info modal
        </b-button>
        <b-button size="sm" @click.stop="row.toggleDetails">
          {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Details
        </b-button>
      </template>
      <template slot="row-details" slot-scope="row">
        <b-card>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="(value, key) in row.item" :key="key">{{ key }}: {{ value}}</li>
          </ul>
        </b-card>
      </template>
    </b-table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was quite simple.
Just change this part

```
<template slot="selected" slot-scope="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="row.value">
        {{row.value}}
</template>
```

to this one

```
 <template slot="selected" slot-scope="data">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="data.item.selected">
 </template>
```

So the scope of this column does not effect the iterators dataset (which is "row" in my case) but the root data set of the data attribute.